# Why is $6\mathbb{Z} + 9\mathbb{Z}$ a principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Ler $R$ denote a commutative ring with identity.

For $R = \mathbb{Z}$, why is the ideal $6\mathbb{Z} + 9\mathbb{Z}$ principal?

Any help where to start would be appreciated.

Comment: You could start by listing the elements of $6\mathbb{Z} + 9\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: -45 -30 15 30 45 ect

Comment: @complexityyy Those are elements but they aren't the only ones. $6\mathbb{Z} + 9\mathbb{Z} \ne 15\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What does Bezout say about $\,6n+9m\,$?

Comment: gcd(6,9) = 3 so $6\mathbb{Z} + 9\mathbb{Z} = 3\mathbb{Z}?$

Comment: Right, one way of stating Bezout is $\ a\Bbb Z + b\Bbb Z = \gcd(a,b)\Bbb Z.\ $ Try proving that.

Comment: And when you do, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: $x \in 6\mathbb{Z} + 9\mathbb{Z} \\ x = 6u+9v \\ u,v \in \mathbb{Z} \\ x \in 3(2u + 3v) \in 3 \mathbb{Z} $ but how does that make it principle?

Comment: which ideals in Z are principal ideals? think about that for a moment.

Comment: You have shown that $6\mathbb{Z} + 9\mathbb{Z} \subset 3\mathbb{Z}$, and you can also see that $9-6=3 \in 6\mathbb{Z} + 9\mathbb{Z}$, which generates $3\mathbb{Z}$. You don't need to know that $n\mathbb{Z} + m\mathbb{Z} = \gcd(n,m)\mathbb{Z}$ to solve this problem.

Comment: @csprun  But that amounts to using the Bezout identity for $\,\gcd(6,9)=3,\,$ exactly as I hinted above.. The general case is just as easy if one knows Bezout.

Comment: so have I already shown it's a principle ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ with a generator of 3?

Comment: That's right, exactly. You've shown every element of the ideal is a multiple of $3$ and that $3$ is an element of the ideal. That's precisely what it means to be principal (with generator $3$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a principle ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ because it is of the form $aR$.
 Where a $\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $R = \mathbb{Z}$.

Hence the generator $a = 3$ is found by:
$x \in 6\mathbb{Z} + 9\mathbb{Z} \\ x = 6u+9v \\ u,v \in \mathbb{Z} \\ x \in 3(2u + 3v) \subset 3 \mathbb{Z}$